# Trying to get pygame documentation code to work

Tags: python, pygame

I'm going through the documentation for pygame 1.9.6 and I've hit page 29 and honestly I just can't make sense of why I can't get it to do what it says it does (make a green rectangle with red dots and black text defining the 4 corners 4 mid points and the center point.

the documentation code can be seen on page 29 at:
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf

I feel like a lot was left out of the example they provided so I've played around with it a little bit but have hit the point where I just want to see how to get it to do what it says it should.

my variation:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.rect import *
from pygame.font import *

def draw_point(text, pos):
    img = font.render(text, True, Black)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, pos, 3)
    screen.blit(img, pos)

SIZE = 500, 200
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAY = (150, 150, 150)
GREEN = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

rect = Rect(50, 40, 250, 80)
##print(f'x={rect.x}, y={rect.y}, w={rect.w}, h={rect.h}')
##print(f'left={rect.left}, top={rect.top}, right={rect.right}, bottom={rect.bottom}')
##print(f'center={rect.center}')

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rect, 4)

    for pt in pts:
        draw_point(pt, eval('rect.'+pt))
        
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _" I can't get it to do what it says it does"_ What does it actually do?

Comment: Well, for starters, you have a loop `for pt in pts:`, but you have no variable named `pts`.

Comment: ... the variable `pts` is on page 25 in the document. `font` is on page 36.

Comment: much appreciated guys, i know my code is all over the place, like i said i had hit the point where i just wanted to see what the final code would look like. thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the complete [document](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf).

The variable `pts` is on page 25

```py
pts = ('topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright', 
       'midtop', 'midright', 'midbottom', 'midleft', 'center')
```

and the variable `font` is on page 36:

```py
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.rect import *
from pygame.font import *

def draw_point(text, pos):
    img = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, pos, 3)
    screen.blit(img, pos)

SIZE = 500, 200
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAY = (150, 150, 150)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
rect = Rect(50, 40, 250, 80)
pts = ('topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright', 
       'midtop', 'midright', 'midbottom', 'midleft', 'center')

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rect, 4)

    for pt in pts:
        draw_point(pt, eval('rect.'+pt))
        
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @RandomDavisv You're right, I just copied the code from the question.

Comment: that's perfect, sorry i guess i was just confused by the way it was laid out in the document! thank you!